# Combining two lists and sorting through reference to dictionary Python

Tags: python, regex, debugging, sorting, dictionary

I have (what seems to me is) a pretty convoluted problem. I'm going to try to be as succinct as possible - though in order to understand the issue fully, you might have to click on my profile and look at the (only other) two questions I've posted on StackOverflow. In short: I have two lists -- one is comprised of email strings that contain a facility name, and a date of incident. The other is comprised of the facility ids for each email (I use one of the following regex functions to get this list). I've used Regex to be able to search each string for these pieces of information. The 3 Regex functions are:

```
def find_facility_name(incident):

    pattern = re.compile(r'Subject:.*?for\s(.+?)\n')
    findPat1 = re.search(pattern, incident)
    facility_name = findPat1.group(1)

    return facility_name



def find_date_of_incident(incident):


    pattern = re.compile(r'Date of Incident:\s(.+?)\n')
    findPat2 = re.search(pattern, incident)
    incident_date = findPat2.group(1)

    return incident_date

def find_facility_id(incident):
    pattern = re.compile('(\d{3})\n')
    findPat3 = re.search(pattern, incident)
    f_id = findPat3.group(1)

    return f_id
```

I also have a dictionary that is formatted like this:

```
d = {'001' : 'Facility #1', '002' : 'Another Facility'...etc.}
```

**I'm trying to COMBINE the two lists and sort by the Key values in the dictionary, followed by the Date of Incident. Since the key values are attached to the facility name, this should automatically caused emails from the same facilities to be grouped together. In order to do that, I've tried to use these two functions:**

```
def get_facility_ids(incident_list):
'''(lst) -> lst

Return a new list from incident_list that inserts the facility IDs from the
get_facilities dictionary into each incident.

'''
f_id = []
for incident in incident_list:
    find_facility_name(incident)
    for k in d:
        if find_facility_name(incident) == d[k]:
            f_id.append(k)

return f_id

id_list = get_facility_ids(incident_list)

def combine_lists(L1, L2):
    combo_list = []
    for i in range(len(L1)):
        combo_list.append(L1[i] + L2[i])

return combo_list

combination = combine_lists(id_list, incident_list)

def get_sort_key(incident):
'''(str) -> tup

Return a tuple from incident containing the facility id as the first
value and the date of the incident as the second value.

'''

return (find_facility_id(incident), find_date_of_incident(incident))

final_list = sorted(combination, key=get_sort_key)
```

Here is an example of what my input might be and the desired output:

```
d = {'001' : 'Facility #1', '002' : 'Another Facility'...etc.}
input: first_list = ['email_1', 'email_2', etc.]
first output: next_list = ['facility_id_for_1+email_1', 'facility_id_for_2 + email_2', etc.]
DESIRED OUTPUT: FINAL_LIST = sorted(next_list, key=facility_id, date of incident)
```

The only problem is, the key values are not matching properly with what's found in each individual email string. Some DO, others are completely random. I have no idea why this is happening, but I have a feeling it has something to do with the way I'm combining the two lists. Can anyone help this lowly n00b? Thanks!!!

Comment: The question is a bit hard to understand. Can you show us some example input, the output you get, and the output you want?

Comment: You have a bunch of emails, but what are you trying to do with them? Extract data from them, replace some codes and output the results in a list?

Comment: "I have two lists -- one is comprised of email strings that contain a facility name, and a date of incident." Ok, what about the second list? It doesn't look like you describe it anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, they other list is comprised of nothing but the extracted facility IDs, will edit now.

Comment: in your i/o example there are no keys! Please don't mix up dictionaries and lists.

Comment: it was previously mentioend, but I'll go ahead and put it as an input anyhow

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly: You have a bunch of email's and you want to have these emails in a list with the facilityid, the date and the email. This list should be ordered by date. Correct?

Comment: by facility id, THEN by date. :) I also need to insert the IDs into the emails before sorting them. so that when I write them to a file, it will show the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I would suggest reversing your ID-to-name dictionary. Looking up a value by key is very fast but finding a key by value is very slow.

```
rd = { name: id_num for id_num, name in d.items() }
```

Then your first function can be replaced by a list comprehension:

```
id_list = [rd[find_facility_name(incident)] for incident in incident_list]
```

This might also expose why you're getting messed up values in your results. If an incident has a facility name that's not in your dictionary, this code will raise a `KeyError` (whereas your old function would just skip it).

Your `combine` function is very similar to Python's built in `zip` function. I'd replace it with:

```
combination = [id+incident for id, incident in zip(id_list, incident_list)]
```

However, since you're building the first list from the second one, it might make sense to build the combined version directly, rather than making separate lists and then combining them in a separate step. Here's an update to the list comprehension above that goes right to the `combination` result:

```
combination = [rd[find_facility_name(incident)] + incident
               for incident in incident_list]
```

To do the sort, you can use the ID string that we just prepended to the email message, rather than parsing to find the ID again:

```
combination.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0:3], get_date_of_incident(x)))
```

The `3` in the slice is based off of your example of `"001"` and `"002"` as the id values. If the actual ids are longer or shorter you'll need to adjust that.

Comment: God...you're a genius. At work now so can't test this out. but this looks really promising!! Will check when I get home later today, and will respond! Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I think is going on. Please correct me if possible.
The 'incident_list' is a list of email strings. You go in and find the facility names in each email because you have an external dictionary that has the (key:value)=(facility id: facility name). From the dictionary, you can extract the facility id in this 'id_list'.

You combine the lists so that you get a list of strings [facility id + email,...]
Then you want it to sort by a tuple( facility id, date of incidence ).

It looks like you are searching for the facility id and the facility name twice. You can skip a step if they are the same. Then, the best way is to do it all at once with tuples:

```
incident_list = ['email1', 'email2',...]

unsorted_list = []
for email in incident list:
    id = find_facility_id(email)
    date = find_date_of_incident(email)
    mytuple = ( id, date, id + email )
    unsorted_list.append(mytuple)

final_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda mytup:(mytup[0], mytup[1]))
```

Then you get an easy list of tuples sorted by first element (id as a string), and then second element (date as a string). If you just need a list of strings ( id + email ), then you need a list with the last element of each tuple part

`FINALLIST = [ tup[-1] for tup in final_list ]`

Comment: This might be helpful...but not sure it addresses how the pairing between facility ID and the emails is not matching properly (is buggy).